# Summary table for the model

Tags: laravel

There is a model ObjectType and a model GuestOptions

I want to create a pivot table, I do this

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('object_type_options', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('object_type_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('guest_option_id');
        $table->foreign('object_type_id')->references('id')->on('object_types')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('guest_option_id')->references('id')->on('guest_options')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['object_type_id','guest_option_id']);
    });
}
```

In the model I define the relation **ObjectType** , but there is no result

```
public function options()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(GuestOptions::class,'object_type_options');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You probably need to also specify the 3rd and 4th parameter of `belongsToMany()`, since your `GuestOptions` model doesn't follow conventions (Model names are Singular, should be `GuestOption`): https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-model-structure. Also, when in doubt, you can do `dd(ObjectType::first()->options()->toSql());`, or `\DB::enableQueryLog(); ObjectType::first()->options()->get(); dd(\DB::getQueryLog());` to see the SQL being used; drop that into a SQL editor and see if any results are returned.

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Models\ObjectType::options()

Comment: But you have the code right there where you define `public function options()` on your `ObjectType` Model... Did you define that in the wrong spot? Cause that would be the first culprit on why this doesn't work 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can give two basic and quick solutions.

```
public function options()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(GuestOptions::class,'object_type_options','object_type_id','guest_option_id');
}
```

you can also use the relation more clearly like below. but need to change some attributes in the database.

```
 public function options()
 {
     return $this->belongsToMany(GuestOptions::class);
 }
```

And Table need to change

```
public function up()
{
    //table name changed
    Schema::create('guest_options_object_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('object_type_id');//actual table name
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('guest_options_id'); //actual table name
        $table->foreign('object_type_id')->references('id')->on('object_types')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('guest_options_id')->references('id')->on('guest_options')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->primary(['object_type_id','guest_option_id']);
    });
}
```